# How to separate values in the same input

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, forms, input

Hey guys, I have two questions. First, how do I separate values in the same input area that are separated with a comma when I'm using php. How can I differentiate them? And second, how can I separate values that use jquery's autosuggest in php?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not quite exact, to be able to provide answer on it..

Comment: @alexanderb I'm using JQuery 's autosuggest function that gives a dropdown menu of suggestions and allows users to select multiple items from the dropdown menu. My question is, when I'm checking the values in php, how can I separate them from each other?

Answer (score 1):

For first question:

```
$values = explode(',', $_POST['values']);
```

$values will be an indexed array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this text input:

```
<input type="text" name="choices">
```

You would explode the value "one,two,three" using:

```
$choices = explode(',', $_GET['choices']); // or $_POST, depending
```

Which leaves you with `$choices == array( 'one', 'two', 'three' )`. Also note that PHP understands a special notation for form fields that return as part of an array:

```
<input type="text" name="choices[]" value="one">
<input type="text" name="choices[]" value="two">
<input type="text" name="choices[]" value="three">
```

This will automatically parse into an array:

```
$choices = $_GET['choices']; // array( 'one', 'two', three' )
```

The second part of your question could use clarification.

Comment: But how can I detect the number of choices given?

Comment: In either case, `count($choices)`.